# i want to split data from database into three columns of table

Tags: php, mysql

i want to split data from database into three columns of table but i don't how to do i have tried but it's not working properly please help me thanks in advance

```
 <?php
 $count=1;
$query1=mysql_query(" SELECT *,category.id ids FROM category INNER JOIN products ON  category.`cid`=products.`cid` WHERE category.id='$id' ") or die ('Product Query Problem');
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    {
    $count++;
?>
```

i want to split data from database into three columns of table but i don't how to do that i have tried it but it's not working properly please help me thanks in advance

```
 <div class="main_content">

<div class="featured-items clearfix">
<div class="items clearfix">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><div class="item-block-1">
<div class="image-wrapper">
<div class="image">
<div class="overlay">
<div class="position">
<div>
<p><?php echo $row1['description']; ?></p>
<a href="pandora-homepage.html#" class="quickshop">Quick shop</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a href=""><img src="products/images/photos/photo-2.jpg" style="margin: -27.5px 0 0 0;" alt="" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<h2><a href=""><?php echo $row1['product']; ?></a></h2>
<p class="price"><?php echo $row1['price']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
if($count%3==1)
{

    ?></td></tr>
  </table>
<?php   }}?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell us how the table looks now and how you want it to look!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: What does the output look like? Where are you inserting the `<td>...</td>` and `<tr>...</tr>` markers that get you to the next cell in the table?

Comment: i want to add 3 products into 3 columns then new product will come into another row of table

Comment: First thing is that the closing tag </table> is inside the $count%3==1 condition. It should be outside the condition.

Comment: @OzairKafray can u give me example

Comment: @candysmith: Look at Floris' answer/ That should be close, if not perfect for you.

Comment: thank you to all i have done .

Answer (score 1):

You will find a very clear example of creating an html table from php [here](http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php). I copy a few relevant lines:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result2)) {
    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
    echo '<tr><th>Field</th><th>Type</th><th>Null</th><th>Key</th><th>Default<th>Extra</th></tr>';
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
       echo '<tr>';
       foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
           echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
       }
       echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table><br />';
}
```

It is echoing all the columns in the table - if you want to do something different you can change the inner `foreach` loop. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      <?php
  $count=1;
 ?>
 <div class="main_content">

<div class="featured-items clearfix">
<div class="items clearfix">
<table border="0">

<?
$query1=mysql_query(" SELECT *,category.id ids FROM category INNER JOIN products ON   category.`cid`=products.`cid` WHERE category.id='$id' ") or die ('Product Query Problem');
 while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
 {
 $count++;
 ?>

  <tr><td><div class="item-block-1">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
  <div class="position">
  <div>
   <p><?php echo $row1['description']; ?></p>
   <a href="pandora-homepage.html#" class="quickshop">Quick shop</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <a href=""><img src="products/images/photos/photo-2.jpg" style="margin: -27.5px 0 0 0;" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <h2><a href=""><?php echo $row1['product']; ?></a></h2>
  <p class="price"><?php echo $row1['price']; ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php
   if($count%3==1)
    {

    ?></td></tr>
   <?php   }}?>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```